# Can I combine Twig with a CSS layout system?

Tags: twig

I am brand new to twig and I have built some basic pages just to test, normally I use a layout system such as the [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) grid system but how does it work with Twig, can you use such as system or does Twig use its own layout system?

Comment: Twig is just a template engine. You can use w/e you want

Comment: @DarkBee how does Twig control layout without something like a layout system?

Comment: Twig does not control anything. It just compiles the twig files you create into PHP. People use template engines because of the tools you are getting with it which increases readability and decreases complexity as you are able to sepperate layout from logic